# Play .swf with Python/Pygame/OcempGUI

Tags: python, flash, pygame

I'm looking at switching programming languages due to some unavoidable roadblocks. However, before I dedicate myself to a whole new language, I need to know if it is possible for me to play .swf or .flv files underneath other GUI elements if I am using OcempGUI and pygame? Will using those two libraries back me into a corner, to where I cannot use other python GUI libraries without a lot of time-consuming patching?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the GUI's features list and usage, it does not appear to support .swf playback. If anyone has evidence to the contrary, an additional answer would be appreciated.